# class active not working on page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I know this question comes across a lot, but I just can't figure out how to do this using the, already answered posts. Here I am having different menus on a single page. When I click on each menu I want that menu to be active but here it's not working.

This is my view page:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="active"> <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url();?>nowaste_control/index#about">About</a> </li>
  <li class=""><a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('nowaste_control/index#product'); ?>">Products</a> </li>
  <li  class=""> <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url();?>nowaste_control/index#technology">Technology</a> </li>
</ul>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.nav navbar-nav li a').click(function($) {
  $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname+window.location.hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','.nav navbar-nav li a',function($) {` instead of `$('.nav navbar-nav li a').click(function($) {` for delegating event

Comment: use document ready statement

Comment: what is the exact problem, not able to trigger click event or not getting class added?

Comment: still now also its not working

Comment: not getting class added

Comment: Your jquery selector got wrong, it is considering one more child under `nav` div, please check my answer.

Comment: I think you're confusing `nav navbar-nav` in an HTML class and the CSS style jQuery selector `$('.nav navbar-nav')` which  would find `navbar-nav` tags that are a child of `.nav`. There is no `navbar-nav` tag actually. Spaces between HTML classes mean that Element has multiple classes. That's not the same as a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample way to do it. By the way. since i cannot have a snippet of you html code for the navigation list i just created a simple one

here is the html i created

```
<div class="nav">
  <li class="active"> <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a> </li>
  <li class=""><a class="page-scroll" href="#product">Products</a> </li>
  <li  class=""> <a class="page-scroll" href="#technology">Technology</a> </li>
</div>
```

here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.nav li a', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kxg2Lb8y/2/)

Comment: thanks a lot..now i understood...you made my day great thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(function(){
    $('.page-scroll').on('click',function(){
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
   });
```

use this to trigger the active class on page load:

```
$(function(){
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$('a[href="'+window.location.href'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: here iam using hash fragment so we need to include that also

Comment: any changes is to be made to the controler

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can wrap your script in `$(function(){..});` so that it will ensure DOM is ready. Also your jquery selector need to be corrected because as per `class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"` your selector must be `.nav.navbar-nav` and not `.nav navbar-nav` (this says there is child `navbar-nav` inside `nav`.  see below code

```
$(function(){
   //here instead of ".nav navbar-nav" change it to ".nav.navbar-nav"
   $('.nav.navbar-nav li a').click(function($) {
   $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname+window.location.hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

And if you are creating these elements dynamically then use `.on()` as shown below -

```
$(function(){
       //here instead of ".nav navbar-nav" change it to ".nav.navbar-nav"
       $(document).on('click','.nav.navbar-nav li a',function($) {
       $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname+window.location.hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
      });
 });
```

Comment: can you try putting alert inside click handler and see if it shows alert. Is there any console errors on browser? Please reproduce your issue on jsfiddle and share the link with us.

Comment: Also check if `window.location.pathname+window.location.hash` this evaluates to correct value i.e. as per you html code values. If not then simply use `$(this).parent().addClass('active');`